# Does spring boot remove the velocity template auto configuration support?

Tags: spring-boot

when I try to config the template resource path for velocity template,Its not working & getting message like "cannot resolve configuration property spring.velocity.resourceLoaderPath".

Comment: Yes. As Spring 5 dropped support for velocity Spring Boot 2 doesn't support Velocity anymore. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What%27s-New-in-Spring-Framework-5.x#removed-packages-classes-and-methods

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification